# How force clients to update JS script if it is loaded via tracking code

Tags: javascript, http, caching

I'm creating React powered application that is loaded in the same manner as Google analitics:

```
<script>
(function(w, d, s, n, a, m) {
  w[n] = w[n] || function() { (w[n].q = w[n].q || []).push(arguments) };
  w[n].l = 1 * new Date();

  a = d.createElement(s);
  a.async = 1;
  a.src = 'https://some.server.io/build/app.js';
  m = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
}(window, document, 'script', 'quant'));
quant('init', 'some-id');
</script>
```

Webmaster put this small snippet into HTML of host webpage and this will initialize small React widget.

As you can see the effect of the snippet is that it will add

```
<script src="https://some.server.io/build/app.js" />
```

to the DOM of the host page.

My question is, how to force clients' browsers to download a new version of the script (`app.js`) if I need ship hotfix for example?

Comment: https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/

Comment: Yeah, since I cannot use the cache-busting technique, I must set short caching using `Expires` header.